# How to un-embed form in symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

```
$twoform = new TwoForm;

$this->embedForm('twoform', $twoform);

 if($value == false) {
  // unembedForm twoform  HOW?
}
```

how can i make if `$value == false` then form `twoform` is not submit and not add to database? unset fields not working, because form is sending, but it has a `NULL` value.

Comment: How do you insert data in database ? my solution won't fix this i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to unset form

`unset($this->widgetSchema['twoForm']);
unset($this->validatorSchema['twoForm']);
unset($this->formFieldSchema['twoForm']);`

But this won't avoid posting the form in cas it was previously visible. You can replace validator to ignore posted values. 
`$this->setValidator('twoForm', new sfValidatorPass());`

If the exemple given is complete, the better is imho not to embed the form if $value == false

The database insertion depends on how your data is saved into it (sfDoctrineForm ?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to override form bind method:

```
public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null) {
  if ($value) {
    unset($this['twoForm']); // UNSET embedded form
  }
  parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
}
```

Here $value may be form option (use $this->getOption('option_name') for this) or some value from the post query (i.e. $taintedValues['widget_name']).